# how to duplicate jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i am a noob and I'm having a real problem duplicating a query slider i downloaded here:
manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery

The problem is that want more than 1 slider on the same page, and I'm not really sure what to copy. And i am pretty sure i would also have to give the copies a new name so there is no duplicate content.

So what do i copy ? and where do i change the name if the new slider ?
see the code here
http://manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery/2/

Hope someone can help

Comment: on the website they write this for another similar slider: "To set multiple scrollers with different style and features on a single page, give them a unique id and add a function call for each one"

Answer (score 1):

The only things to change are the  `img href attributes`  tags  for example :

JUST CHANGE THE PATH AFTER HREF= "path to your image here" ,EVERYTHING ELSE IS THE SAME.

```
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_lux.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_lux_thumb.jpg" title="Lux Aeterna" alt="Lux Aeterna" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_dk.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_dk_thumb.jpg" title="X-Wing on patrol" alt="X-Wing on patrol" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_albireo.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_albireo_thumb.jpg" title="Albireo Outpost" alt="Albireo Outpost" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_church.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_church_thumb.jpg" title="Church of Heaven" alt="Church of Heaven" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_Decampment.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_Decampment_thumb.jpg" title="Decampment" alt="Decampment" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_Hibernaculum.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_Hibernaculum_thumb.jpg" title="Hibernaculum" alt="Hibernaculum" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_lucernarium.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_lucernarium_thumb.jpg" title="Supremus Lucernarium" alt="Supremus Lucernarium" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_moons.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_moons_thumb.jpg" title="Aurea Mediocritas" alt="Aurea Mediocritas" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_praedestinatio.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_praedestinatio_thumb.jpg" title="Praedestinatio" alt="Praedestinatio" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_transitorius.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_transitorius_thumb.jpg" title="Transitorius" alt="Transitorius" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div><a href="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_victimofgravity.jpg"><img src="images/Universe_and_planets_digital_art_wallpaper_victimofgravity_thumb.jpg" title="Victim of Gravity" alt="Victim of Gravity" class="thumb" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: aaah .. I see.. Did you try to just copy and paste the code within the body tags twice?

Comment: U should be able to use the functions more then once though

Comment: yes i know. The problem i have now is that when i copy the whole thing the new slider is just put into the existing one. It "extends it" since that is the result when i copy all, then i know its just a small change for it to work.